# Django superuser creation issue

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my view where the user can login to the application, I have the following view handler:

```
# Login Page
def login(request):
    # First check if the user is already logged in
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print "User is authenticated"
        # Yes - redirect to control panel home page
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/control-panel')
```

Thus, if the user is already logged in, I do not allow the login page to be shown and instead redirect to the control panel page which is like the home page for users that have logged in.

Now, in my view handler for registration of new users page, I have the following code:

```
def register(request):
    # Assume that I have code that handles all form processing etc.
    # Create super user
    user = User.objects.create_superuser(username=username,
                                         email=email, password=password)
    # Redirect to login page
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login?registration_success=1')
```

What I want is that once the user registers, I save the user in the DB and then redirect the user to the login page - the user is expected to login after registering.

However, what happens is that the user seems to have already logged in and thus, as can be seen in the code for the login page view handler, the user is redirected to the control panel page.

How do I just create the super user (but not log the user in) and then force the user the login after registering?

EDIT: If I register the user as a non-superuser, then it does not log the user in automatically. Thus if I use `User.objects.create_user(...)` instead, the user is not logged in. Only super users are automatically logged in which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually log him off after the register..

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

logout(request)
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but I don't want to explicitly log the user out. Is there something that creates the user but does not log him in?